# What did agent Patterson study to have those skills?

Tags: science-fiction, blindspot

In the blindspot serie, there is an special agent called: Patterson

[image]

Her job is help to the team from it's laboratory(at the beginning). She seems to have a high knowledge about:

- Hacking
- App development
- Surveillance
- Project Management
- Commercial Airline Piloting
- Bomb Disposal
- Counter-Terrorism
- Puzzles
- Linguistics
- Geography
- International Relations
- Hostage Negotiation
- Drug Counseling
- Biology
- Chemistry
- Physics
- Medicine
- etc

If is possible to have these amount of knowledge for a human, what has she studied?

Or what kind or university/institute real career is close to have people able to do what she does?

Maybe is a pure fiction, but would be interesting to know: What did she study to have those skills?

Thanks

Comment: It's certainly possible. Look up the term [polymath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) You could get those skills with two good university degrees & a career in the military, which even could be concurrent. One of my nieces has two totally unrelated masters degrees which would almost cover all your list except for the military aspects & she's only in her late 20s.

Comment: Could you put this as an answer? Is exactly what I asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not beyond the realms of possibility that someone could have good working knowledge of that subject list. For someone to be an absolute authority on them all might be a bit of an exaggeration for plot purposes.

The basics could come from simply a good school, followed by university. It's not unknown for people to obtain more than one masters degree whilst still in their twenties. If that further education was done as part of a military career, that would also explain some other aspects. That the character now works for the FBI would complete the list.

The term used for someone with high competency in multiple subjects is **[polymath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath)**

Broadly you could cover it like this (some are repeated as you could pick them up from multiple sources)…

- Good schooling
  Puzzles
  Linguistics
  Geography
- Medical degree
  Drug Counseling
  Biology
  Chemistry
  Physics
  Medicine
- Computer sciences
  Hacking
  App development
  Project Management
  Puzzles
- Military/FBI
  Surveillance
  Piloting
  Counter-Terrorism
  International Relations
  Hostage Negotiation
  Linguistics
  Geography